# I want "File does not exist" errors to be ignored or not logged

Tags: php, flash, apache, file, logging

> [Sat Nov 19 13:17:04 2011] [error] [client 1.1.1.32] File does
> not exist: /var/www/vhosts/x.com/httpdocs/scores.asp
>
> [Sat Nov 19 13:17:54 2011] [error] [client 1.1.1.32] File does
> not exist: /var/www/vhosts/x.com/httpdocs/reqewrqwe.awwe

Solved thanks

Comment: Also take a look at http://serverfault.com/questions/36589/apache2-how-to-avoid-logging-certain-missing-files-into-error-log

Answer (score 5):

Create a [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) and return an empty file in response to the URLs you'd like to remove from the logs:

```
RewriteRule scores\.asp$ - [L]
```

In case you don't have any pattern for the URLs and you want to prevent for all non-existing files, add a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

Or just with a more current apache:

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

and then `index.php` giving a 404 status response:

```
<?php
header("Status: 404 Not Found", 1, 404);
```

The `index.php` file must exists, otherwise (for the `RewriteRule`) this would create an endless loop.

Alternatively this might work (and won't require the `index.php` file):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [R=404,L]
```

See: [Apache2: how to avoid logging certain missing files into error.log](https://serverfault.com/q/36589)

Comment: +1 alternatively, if that creates problems with the Flash app, rewrite to `scores.php` instead and have that file emit a 404 header

Comment: Sorry guys, I realize that I didn't give enough details. I just edit the first message. Please check.

Comment: @öksürdüm: Extended the answer with alternative options you have.

Comment: I get these errors now: "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error."

Comment: Use `FallbackResource` instead *or* (my fault), use the `index.php` as well for the RewriteRule, I'll update the answer.