# Exclude apache logging of map tiles only from error_log

Tags: apache, error-log

My server provides map tiles for a map covering a limited area.
Currently every request for a tile not within the map area produces a
"File does not exist" message in apache's error_log.  This is useless
information and greatly clutters up the error_log - so finding
"real" errors is difficult, requiring filtering through grep, etc.,
besides creating an inordinately large error_log.  But I DO want the
valid requests to appear in apache's access_log, since I want to count
them to determine usage.

I have not found any reasonable solution which allows me to
exclude the invalid tile requests from error_log while keeping valid ones
in access_log.  Reading apache docs and searching on-line, the
"solutions" I have found are

() use apache "SetEnvIf" directive to set an environmental variable to
be used by "CustomLog" - but this will exclude the selected files from
*both* logs.  "ErrorLog" cannot utilize an environmental variable

() use "RewriteCond" & "RewriteRule" to send a 404 "not found" for the
"invalid" requests.  Presumably this would work, but would require
creating a large list of "invalid file" expressions - and I assume
that such a long list of filters would reduce the server performance
for all files.  This does not seem practical.

(For those unaware, the tiles are stored in a pyramid of directories,
the topmost directory representing the zoom level and nested subdirectories
representing x/y positions, producing requests ala
.../TILES/10/167/403.png.  So a partial area coverage map such as mine
is analogous to a "sparse" array in that there are many non-existent
subdirectories at any level, which a map display app may try to access.]

I'm hoping to get some relatively simple solution.  I'm a little
surprised that excluding files only from the error_log seems to not be
possible, since I would think my situation not uncommon.

Later - though about whether there might be a way to send all TILE requests to a separate access/error log combo - then I could could accesses to the former and ignore the latter.  But from what I can see, error messages must all go to a single file.

Even later - found this, which seems a viable solution if placed in .htaccess file in my TILES directory, instead of in the apache config file
[I want "File does not exist" errors to be ignored or not logged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196718/i-want-file-does-not-exist-errors-to-be-ignored-or-not-logged)

Answer (score 0):

Per my last addition, I put following in .htaccess file in my TILES directory and missing tile files are no longer being added to error_log

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [G,L]
```